# Html back link to specific element

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I have a webpage that loads thumbnail images (they are around 150) using jquery lazy loading. As we scroll down, more images are added.

The issue is, lets say you click on 70th image, it will open a new page showing the full size image, but when user go back to previous page using the browser back button, it doesn't go to that 70th image. Please remember, there are 3 images per row, so when user go backs he is not on the row the thumbnail was present.

So is there any way so that when users clicks back on the browser button ( or i can add a back link if necessary) to that same thumbnail ?

Comment: Assuming the dynamically loaded images have anchor ids, do you have the ability that as the user scrolls and they enter focus, that you can update the URL -- that way when you return to the page via the back button, you've maintained at least some point of relative position on the page?

Comment: maybe someone can figure out how http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icons/ does it without hash fragments...

Comment: Why not display the image with JS, too? Lightbox, ...

Comment: Or update history to reflect the image's ID in the URL. http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: That is what i want to understand, i am quite newbie to javascript, any hint is appreciated ?